# Find files with specific extension and restrict permission to specific user

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

I am looking for command which can Find files with specific extension and also I want to restrict those files permission to specific user.

I tried below command its listing all files and folders.

```
find . -type f -name "*.log" | ls -lr
```

I am looking for shell script for the same

Please suggest on this any command

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `-user` find test option, to filter by user.

From find man page:

```
-user uname
       File is owned by user uname (numeric user ID allowed).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to set permissions for a specific user based on the files found, you can use:

```
find /home/foo -name "*.xml" -type f -exec setfacl -m "u:foo:rwx" '{}' \;
```

Find all files in the example /home/foo directory with the extension xml and then set extended permissions for a specific user (foo in this case)